# Facebook getUser() not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect to the php facebook sdk and pull user data.

```
<?php


 require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook= new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '2453463636',
      'secret' => '365653656565656',
      'allowSignedRequest' => false,
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
   // $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100),first_name,last_name,username,email');
    echo $user_profile['email'];

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
}

?>
```

This works well on localhost while testing. I have a app created on facebook for this with a website platform added with the locahost as the site url in the dashboard.

To now test on the server I created another app on facebook with the domain and site url set as my staging site on my server.

I simply changed the appId and secret to that of the Facebook App created with the remote staging site url address, but this doesn't work.

Help Please! Is there something key that I missed in the code or dashboard that is not causing my page to get the user?

My page is a view in a codeigniter application, and `require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');`, this directory resides in the root of my codeigniter application

**EDIT:**

I replace the die clause with `die("failed");`, and the text "failed" shows up when I try to load the page. Not sure what the problem is? This worked fine on localhost, why am I noy connecting now?

When I `print_r($user);` the page returns 0. Why am I not connecting.

Comment: Well the “loop” you kinda created yourself, because on failed login you redirect just back there … As for the problem, check if your session is working correctly, i.e. if the session id gets passed along as it should.

Comment: @CBroe  Well I followed this code from the developers guide, this is the latest version of the sdk. The guide said nothing about starting a session. How is this done in this version?

Comment: @CBroe Please see edit above